# For loop gives all the list instead of one item in robot framework

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

I have this code:

```
Test Check For Loop
    @{ret_val} =    Read Data From Excel    ${filename}      ${sheetname}
    log to console      ${ret_val}
    :FOR    ${item}     IN      ${ret_val}
    \   log to console      ${item}
```

`Read Data From Excel` is one of the other keywords which I have developed and it works fine; but I got this output:

```
Test Check For Loop                                           [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario.scenario                                                     | PASS |
0 critical tests, 0 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenario                                                              | PASS |
0 critical tests, 0 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

As you see, `${item}` is exactly the same as `${ret_val}`. I'm iterating over the list and `${item}` should be one the items existing in the list which means it should be a dictionary. So the second print should be:

```
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

Any idea why the framework does not iterate and returns the whole list instead of the item?

**EDIT 1:**

I have solved the issue according to @Laurent Bristiel's answer. I should write the list variable as below:

```
:FOR    ${item}     IN      @{ret_val}
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged "Python"? I don't see how it relates...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @martineau. I usually work with python and it was a mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code

1) when you do a FOR over a variable, use @{variable} instead of $(variable)
See [doc about loop in Robot User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#normal-for-loop).

2) the arrary you are looping over is an array with a single element (a dict) so you will get only one element (the dict)
Maybe you would like to loop over the items, values or keys of your index. 
See [Collections documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) for that.
Here is an example where I loop over all the items of the dict.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test Check For Loop
    # @{ret_val} =    Read Data From Excel    ${filename}      ${sheetname}
    # this creates something like: [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
    # let's mock this keyword and build the dict of array ourselves
    ${dict} =  create dictionary  key1  val1  key2  val2
    @{ret_val} =  create list  ${dict}

    log to console  ${\n}Object we want to parse: ${ret_val}
    # This shows: [{u'key2': u'val2', u'key1': u'val1'}]
    # which is an array with only 1 element, which is a dict

    :FOR  ${item}  IN  @{ret_val}
    \   log to console  Parsing with FOR over the array: ${item}
    # whith this you get your only element

    ${dict} =  get from list  ${ret_val}  0
    ${items} =  Get Dictionary Items  ${dict}
    log to console  Parsing with FOR over the dict content
    :FOR  ${item}  IN  @{items}
    \   log to console  Item: ${item}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ pybot for.robot
==============================================================================
For
==============================================================================
Test Check For Loop                                                   
Object we want to parse: [{u'key2': u'val2', u'key1': u'val1'}]
Parsing with FOR over the array: {u'key2': u'val2', u'key1': u'val1'}
Parsing with FOR over the dict content
Item: key1
Item: val1
Item: key2
Item: val2
Test Check For Loop                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For                                                                   | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you! The first note you gave me was exactly the problem. I should have used `@{ret_val}`.

Comment: I think it's the second time you're saving me! :-D