# How to find the largest number from the list of integer items in Robot framework?

Tags: list, robotframework

Can anyone please help me how to find the largest integer from given list using Robot framework.

```
${list} = [2,45,32,55,332,5,5]
```

I want the highest number to be returned as my output.

Comment: Could you use foreach .... Maybe that helps you: [For loop gives all the list instead of one item in robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765075/for-loop-gives-all-the-list-instead-of-one-item-in-robot-framework)

Comment: The code you posted is not valid robot framework syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `${list}` has a valid python list of numbers, you can use the [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to call python's `max` function to easily find the largest value.

The following example assumes that `${list}` is an actual python list of integers, and uses robot's special syntax for converting robot variables python variables (eg: `$list`).

```
${max}=    Evaluate    max($list)
Should be equal as numbers    ${max}    332
```